How to copy full external drive to larger drive when plugging causes crash
I have a linux machine running, and an external hard drive which is full. I want to dd all of the data to a new larger drive. However, just simply plugging it in crashes my host. If I boot with it plugged in, I get a cpu hard lockup. Is there a way to get this plugged in to something which will allow me to copy it to a larger disk if simply plugging it in causes a crash?

I managed to find another machine I'm able to mount this drive and I can rsync it to another drive.
